# Return RedirectView from inside other View

Tags: django

I need to return RedirectView from inside other view:

The BarView looks like this:

```
class BarView(RedirectView):
  def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ..
    return 'some_url.html'
```

And then FooView:

```
class FooView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  ..
  return BarView.as_view()
```

Or should FooView return `HttpResponseRedirect`?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(BarView)
```

Would apprecite your help.